# What is this subgroup called?

Tags: group-theory

Im thinking of the subgroup of the modular group generated by $$z\rightarrow z+a $$ and $$ z\rightarrow -1/z$$ for fixed integer $a$. Is there a name?

Comment: What group are we talking about exactly?

Comment: The group generated by the matricies {{1, a}, {0, 1}} and {{0, -1}, {1, 0}} for fixed integer a not equal to 0. When a is 1 we have SL(2, Z). If its not 1, its a subgroup of the modular group. Is there a precise name for this subgroup?

Comment: Ahm. I'm a bit confused. If one talks about the *modular group* then one usually speaks of the group of linear fractional transformations (with integer values) of the upper half of the complex plane, right? Anyway if $a = 1$ you have generators for the whole modular group, i.e. $PSL(2, \mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z}_2 * \mathbb{Z}_3$.

Comment: I very much doubt these subgroups have names apart from the cases $|a|\le 2$ when they $PSL(2,Z)$ as M.U. noted and its finite index subgroup, respectively. (Infinite index otherwise.) Just give them any name you like, e.g. $PSL_a(2,Z)$ and proceed with something more interesting. As abstract groups, when $|a|>1$, they are all isomorphic to $Z\star Z_2$ if this is what you care about.